# Read images from file path with SDK 30 scoped storage enforced

Tags: android-studio, imageview, filepath, scoped-storage

I have a problem resulting from scoped storage starting API 29 & 30.
I can successfully save images to the allowed Pictures folder using the Mediastore API, and i save the image path to my database.
then when loading data, i get the path and set the picture to imageView using glide library.
in the past few weeks this stopped working, the app can no longer access the images in regular way. I've also tried using a file provider, but that doesn't help either.
if i lower the target sdk to 28 everything works fine, but that's a temporary fix, please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these links for more info, I'm working through this as well in my app. This only applies if you have set targetSdkVersion 30.
While Google's documentation isn't great, this was the best information I've been able to find to learn more about this:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955 (make sure to expand the sections at the bottom of this page)

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/mwaqn1/scoped_storage_recap/ (this one focuses more on Scoped Storage)